# Infer variable type in generic interface

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following example.

```
enum Foo {
    bar,
    baz
}

interface IBar {
    qux: number
}

interface IBaz {
    quux: string
}

type InterfaceType<T> = 
    T extends Foo.bar ? IBar :
    T extends Foo.baz ? IBaz : never;
    
interface ICorge<T> {
    foo: T
    attributes: InterfaceType<T>
}

const grault: Array<ICorge<unknown>> = [
    {
        foo: Foo.bar,
        attributes: {
            qux: 404
        }
    }, {
        foo: Foo.baz,
        attributes: {
            quux: "not found"
        }
    }   
]
```

I want the type of my interface `ICorge` to be automatically infered from the type of `foo`. Is there a way to do that correctly in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a ceremony with types. A bit more practical type solution:

```typescript
interface IBar {
    foo: 'bar'
    attributes: {
      qux: number
    }
}

interface IBaz {
    foo: 'baz'
    attributes: {
      quux: string
    }
}

const grault: (IBar | IBaz)[] = [
    {
        foo: 'bar',
        attributes: {
            qux: 44
        }
    }, {
        foo: 'baz',
        attributes: {
            quux: "not found"
        }
    }   
]
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBzEbN)

At least I'd strongly advise against `enums` in production code unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: This is just a simple example from a much more complexe problem and using your solution would add a lot of repetition. But as a matter of curiosity, why would you advice against `enums`?

Comment: They create a lot of extra code and might significanly decrease performance when used excessivly. I'd assume to use `const enum` as a good tradeoff if you like `enums`.

Comment: Anyway. `InterfaceType` looks really heavy. You can achive the same result with simple mapping type: https://tsplay.dev/mbkRbW . or with enums: https://tsplay.dev/mA7EXw

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I had the `|` done wrong.

Just do:

```js
const grault: Array<ICorge<Foo.bar> | ICorge<Foo.baz>> = [
    {
        foo: Foo.bar,
        attributes: {
            qux: 404
        }
    }, {
        foo: Foo.baz,
        attributes: {
            quux: "not found"
        }
    }   
]
```

See it the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAsAKCpqAjAhgJwBp0sdcAvdAX3XQEsQAXYfAM1wGNgoBJAIQLISWAI5gAHgC4o4CNhbVaaBszadu-CkIyiwE6QGdG+BgHNFadIwCeABw1MW7LgBU7wADwuAfFAC8UMKYLlDA4swgACYGsAgAdHj4UAD8vAJJkkFQIWER0bFwCVqpmuRQ0iDAAG4sANxZ9I5qXLwAwnD4pp4+2qSsCNIuWbiMxnTYYMwG0jxNzsBu9l7eFugccCBGUKb4uGAANozSAIL4u9YePO2dnvCFib4APm0dXR53ReTevgEA2lmoHSkTD9ODSD6JYhA4EjMYTKbSQHA5FQMRSKAAFgADBisqQaNCqIReijQeD4nhyFCUVBYSZ4cBpiSaZgxPooAAiEBwRhQfpgKIcvFYAn4rDoAC6QA)

Comment: This is so simple, the more I discover typescript generics the more I like them. Thank you.